# Amazon Alexa Recording custom words

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Do you guys know if Alexa can register a custom user said word that is no a AMAZON.Something, now that AMAZON.literal (which was a catch all for any word) is deprecated.

For example for a skill like "wikipedia". Whereby I want to be able to say "Hey alexa, wikipedia {word}" without having to have a custom slot type with all words on wikipedia. Would that be possible ?

Answer (score 0):

That is a common concern, so Amazon published this blog post to address it:

Why a Custom Slot is the Literal Solution (November 25, 2016)
https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx3IHSFQSUF3RQP/Why-a-Custom-Slot-is-the-Literal-Solution